# Entityframework Load certain columns of a list withing a entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Heey, Lets assume we have a Teacher and a student relation, the teacher is responsible for a group of students. Now lets say i want to load all the information of a teacher, given his or her id, including the students this teacher is responsible for, however from those students i only want to load the column containing the name, so not the Age and the StudentNumber (see below). Now my question is, how would i do that?

In a attempt to solve this problem i found this   https://colinmackay.scot/2011/07/31/getting-just-the-columns-you-want-from-entity-framework/ , what is almost similar to my situation, however the example shown in the link would return a list of strings, where as i want the teacher to be returned.

Classes:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get { return Set<Teacher>(); } }
}


public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}



public class Students
{
    [Key]
    public int DatabaseID { get; private set; }
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Example of loading:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Teacher = LoadTeacher(4);
        foreach(var student in Teacher.Students)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
        }
    }


    public static Teacher LoadTeacher(int teacherID)
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            return context.Teachers.Where(t => t.ID == teacherID)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
                                   //At this part is my question, how would i make sure that only the name of those students are loaded and not the Age and the StudentNumber? 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select in your context what you want to return.
And the return this as Anonymous object

Like this:

```
public static IQueryable LoadTeacher(int teacherID)
{
    using (var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        var retVal = from teacher in context.Teachers
                     where teacher.ID == teacherID
                     select new {
                           Teacher = teacher,
                           StudentNames = from student in teacher.Students
                                          select student.Name
                           }
         return retVal;
    }
}
```

Then you can access this object from your calling Method.

Comment: Returning anonymous class types is not recommended. The answer would be better with definition of an explicitely defined transfer type.

Comment: In my opinion it depends what you want to do with the result.
If you just want to Display this in a table of your web-application it is commonly useful to put it in a Json-object and therefore you dont need a defining class for your Result, so your Project won't become bigger and bigger with each query

Comment: This seems to be the best solution until now.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) perhaps which:

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
public static Teacher LoadTeacher(int teacherID)
{
    using (var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        return context.Teachers.Where(t => t.ID == teacherID)
                                .Select(t => new Teacher() { Name = t.Name })
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: @msanz No, the provider only selects the columns used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the name of the students like this with lambda query

```
teachers.First(t => t.ID == 10).Students.SelectMany(s=> s.Name)
```

**Edit**

In case you need teacher object as well

```
teachers.Where(t => t.ID == 10).Select(t=>new {teacher= t,studenNames =t.Students.SelectMany(s => s.Name) }).First()
```

Comment: This is indeed a good solution if you only need the names, however in my case i prefer to also get the teacher object from the same query.

Comment: Yes that is where i am looking for :P  (it is the same as the solution provided by @Yggras, where as i assume you didn't saw it)

Comment: I didn't see it. :D 
But anyways, I like Lambda more than linq. it is a lot more understandable